# Slow GCC linker (SDL 2 program)

Tags: c++, gcc, eclipse-cdt

The linker takes ~12 seconds for a very simple SDL 2 application which is very frustrating. Is it normal? I have a feeling I am doing something wrong here:

- Eclipse CDT (Luna)
- Debug mode
- TDM-GCC-64
- Windows 8.1
- i5-4670k 3.40GHz
- 32 GB Ram
- All tools and libs are located on SSD (Samsung) drive.

**Compilation of CPP class takes ~ 3 seconds**

```
g++ -std=c++1y "-IS:\\tools\\CPP\\libs\\sdl\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\Appum.o" "..\\src\\Appum.cpp"
```

**This bit takes ~12 seconds**

```
g++ "-LS:\\tools\\CPP\\libs\\sdl\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\lib" "-LS:\\tools\\CPP\\libs\\SDL2_mixer-2.0.0\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\lib" "-LS:\\tools\\CPP\\libs\\sdl2_image\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\lib" -o Appum.exe "src\\lib\\xml\\tinyxml2.o" "src\\lib\\window\\Window.o" "src\\lib\\window\\MouseInput.o" "src\\lib\\window\\KeyInput.o" "src\\lib\\system\\uuid\\Guid.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\node\\impl\\particles\\ParticleEmitterNode.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\node\\impl\\particles\\Particle.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\node\\impl\\PointSceneNode.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\node\\impl\\ImageSceneNode.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\node\\impl\\DummyNode.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\node\\SceneNode.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\animator\\impl\\RotationAnimation.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\animator\\NodeAnimator.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\Screen.o" "src\\lib\\scene\\SceneManager.o" "src\\lib\\assets\\TextureAsset.o" "src\\lib\\assets\\SoundAsset.o" "src\\lib\\assets\\MusicAsset.o" "src\\lib\\assets\\AssetManager.o" "src\\lib\\assets\\Asset.o" "src\\game\\LogoScreen.o" "src\\Appum.o" -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_image 

21:54:32 Build Finished (took 15s.968ms)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try on Linux? Its [gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) linker is quite fast. Myabe you should consider switching to Linux

Comment: How does the time change if you compile with optimizations (say `-O1`)?

Comment: -01 compilation + linking goes down to 3s.894ms, this is great, 4x improvement, need to google for explanation :) Thank you!

Comment: What's the size of your object files with and without optimization? That could be a reason. You could give the lld a try. Its the linker from the LLVM project. They claim to be faster, but the Windows support is not yet complete.

Comment: 60mb (-o0) vs 48mb (-o1)